# How to stop a fast ride in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

There is a mission that I should retrieve a Coquette, which is quite fast. I tried to do a drive-by with my Micro SMG at the back, but the car won't damage much, and the driver was still alive for 1.5 hour chase. I end up messing up the traffic, getting out from my ride, and popping the driver through windshield.

Any better way to stop a fast ride?

Note: I tried to pop the tires too, no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is the one described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/135826/55487): the trick is to force the other car to stop in a way it would take time for the NPC to actually drive around you. Just stop your car in front of the other won't usually work. Force it in a corner.

Another way, which I found way easier, is to shoot the driver dead. Don't aim the back of the car, aim the head of the driver! There are multiple ways to do this:

- stops your car in front of his car and shoot at him
- approach his car from a side and shoot him
- shoot from behind aiming the windshield, you will eventually kill him

Answer (score 0):

Don't shoot at him, drive in front of his car so it stops and enter the car.
He will flee for you when you shoot at him.

Comment: I tried. He will turn around & escape if I stop in front of him.

Comment: Make sure he can't drive away.